# Matlab: Intersection point between 3D surface and curve

Tags: matlab, 3d, intersection, raytracing

I am facing a ray tracing problem using MATLAB and now I am a bit frustrated. I have some points in the 3D space that define a surface. I represented it with small 3-D triangles using the Delaunay algorithm with the matlab function "trisurf". Then, I have my "ray", that is basically a 3-D vector. My target is to find the point of intersection (X, Y, Z) between this vector (that is a curve, not a straight line). Does exist in matlab a function able to do this or anyone has any suggestion? Thanks in advance for your help,

Leonardo

Answer (score 0):

> I represented it with small 3-D triangles using the Delaunay algorithm with the matlab function "trisurf".

This sounds like a triangle mesh to me.

> I have my "ray", that is basically a 3-D vector.

A ray is a point of origin and a direction, so it should be two vectors, not one.

> My target is to find the point of intersection (X, Y, Z) between this vector (that is a curve, not a straight line).

If you have a set of triangles and a ray, then you can loop over all the triangles and perform a ray/triangle intersection test on each one.

There are a number of algorithms for the intersection test. A popular one is [Moeller-Trumbore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm).

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply. Sorry if I did not explain very well my problem, but I am quiet new in Matlab. My curve is an array with size [1*81] for each dimension (I plot my curve with plot3...). I already tried the algorithm of Moeller-Thumbore (which is implemented in Matlab with the function TriangleRayIntersection), but apparently works only if my "ray" is a straight line not a "curve" as in my case...